# How to configure SSL between Spark and Cassandra?

Tags: apache-spark, ssl, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to configure SSL for the Cassandra Spark connector, but I couldn't find an example of how to do it.

I'm trying to configure it like this:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("someApp")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "111.111.111.111")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.enabled", "true")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.path", "/some/tfile.jks")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.password", "apassword")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.type", "JKS")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.enabledAlgorithms", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.keyStore.path", "/some/kfile.jks")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.keyStore.password", "anotherpassword")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.keyStore.type", "JKS")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.protocol", "TLS");
```

When I try to submit the spark job, I get these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.spark.connector.util.ConfigCheck$ConnectorConfigurationException: Invalid Config Variables
Only known spark.cassandra.* variables are allowed when using the Spark Cassandra Connector.
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.keyStore.password is not a valid Spark Cassandra Connector variable.
No likely matches found.
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.enabled is not a valid Spark Cassandra Connector variable.
No likely matches found.
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.protocol is not a valid Spark Cassandra Connector variable.
No likely matches found.
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.keyStore.type is not a valid Spark Cassandra Connector variable.
No likely matches found.
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.path is not a valid Spark Cassandra Connector variable.
No likely matches found.
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.enabledAlgorithms is not a valid Spark Cassandra Connector variable.
No likely matches found.
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.keyStore.path is not a valid Spark Cassandra Connector variable.
No likely matches found.
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.password is not a valid Spark Cassandra Connector variable.
No likely matches found.
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.type is not a valid Spark Cassandra Connector variable.
No likely matches found.
```

So I'm not sure if this is supported or I'm just using the wrong property names.

I saw this [ticket](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-118) for release 1.2.3 of the connector, but I couldn't find an example of how to use it and it sounded like it may not support keystores.  I'm using version 1.4.0-M1 of the connector.

Can anyone show me an example of how to configure SSL for the Spark Cassandra connector?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Though I don't see any **keystore** configurations, I can see below config variables and they are working fine for me.

**Note**: I am using 1.5.0-M1 version. Not sure if there is any other bug in the version you are using.

```
sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.enabled", "true");
sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.password", "password");
sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.path", "jks file path");
```